# Cannot find classes once ASP.NET website is hosted

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, hosting, app-code

My project is an ASP.Net website that connects to an SQL database.
It compiles fine locally in Visual Studio, but once it is hosted (myWindowsHosting.com) it throws this error:

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

 Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IDefaultView' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:

Line 9:  namespace HFDB2
Line 10: {
Line 11:     public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page, IDefaultView
Line 12:     {
Line 13:         public event EventHandler btnNextClicked;
```

In this example I am trying to implement an Interface to the Default webform. But a similar error occurs for any class I try to reference.

**Why cant my project find any classes once it is hosted?**

Does it have anything to do with my folder structure?

[image]

My classes  are not in an App_Code folder because apparently you dont need one for websites. I tried putting them in an App_Code folder anyway, but it gave a different error.

Note that I uploaded everything you see inside my project folder to the host.

Comment: You are not by any chance deploying your source code to the server are you? If so then you should be deploying the compiled DLLs.

Comment: Yes I am. So all the classes in the above image should be in DLLs?

Comment: Never deploy source code. The easiest way of creating your collection of files to deploy is to use the Publish option in visual studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was deploying my application incorrectly. As Ben Robinson's comment says:

> Never deploy source code. The easiest way of creating your collection of files to deploy is to use the Publish option in visual studio.